# Sun App Server Deployment Error

Tags: java, jsp, web-deployment, application-server

`Sun App Server Deployment` : When choose to precompile JSP : Throw this error

```
 com.sun.enterprise.admin.common.exception.MBeanConfigException:
 Component not registered then have to do asadmin undeploy
```

Anyone know what is the reason for this error?

Comment: Maybe you could give some more information. What is it that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

That's a thing that sometime happens with j2ee apps. You just have to follow the deployment process correctly.